# What is the diffrence between "fragment" and "fragement"

Tags: linux, hardware, device-tree, nvidia-jetson

I'm troubleshooting a device-tree and have come across the keywords "fragment" and "frag***e***ment" in my decompiled blob. At first, I thought it was a typo, but I see the same thing in dtb file provided by NVIDIA in the Linux for Tegra source code.

I can't find any information on what a fragement is and how/if it differs from a fragment.

Comment: It looks like it's just a typo to me.

Comment: I agree. I believe this is just a common misspelling of `fragment` that appears to have made it's way into nvidia code (which is kind of funny). I'm not an nvidia expert though so perhaps there is something to that `e` that isn't in their documentation.

Comment: I saw it mentioned in another [post](https://support2.windriver.com/index.php?page=defects&on=view&id=LINCD-5746), but maybe you two are right.

Comment: it was a spelling issue nothing else